# Build deb package version with command line option

Tags: command-line, deb, packaging, debuild

Newbie to build deb package. I've a build script to generate packages for Ubuntu. Version number is there in changelog. I'd like to automate the process of building deb packages without touching changelog using a version file and the file consists of only version number something like 1.0.0.

How can I pass the version number to debuild command?

```
debuild --no-lintian --preserve-envvar=PATH --check-dirname-level 0 --no-tgz-check -uc -us
```

Comment: You add it to `debian/changelog` using the `dch` command. `debuild` will then pick up the version from `debian/changelog`

Comment: I would like to pass as an option to `debuild` instead of updating changelog and reading again from changelog. `version` should come up from another file which stored in different place.

Comment: too bad. The build system expects version information to be in `debian/changelog`. Feel free to submit a feature request for `dpkg-buildpackage`

Comment: I though of updating version from `debuild/dpkg-buildpackage` instead of updating changelog, So I ended up doing this with `dch` - `sudo dch -v "${version}" -D "trusty" "latest master"`

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up doing this using - `sudo dch -v "${version}" -D "trusty" "all latest updates"`